# Loop over uploaded files and return an array of file signatures

Tags: javascript, arrays, fileapi

I want to loop over files selected for upload, get the file signature and return a array of file signatures. The `listOfFileSignatures` array is empty outside the `readFirstFourBytes` function. Is their a way to make it accessible globally?

```
var listOfFileSignatures = [];
var totalSize;
var uploadedFiles = document.getElementById("notes").files;
for (file of uploadedFiles) {
    var blob = file;
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onloadend = function readFirstFourBytes(e) {
        var arr = (new Uint8Array(e.target.result)).subarray(0, 4);
        var fileSignature = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            fileSignature += arr[i].toString(16);
        };
        listOfFileSignatures.push(fileSignature);
        console.log(listOfFileSignatures); // Array(3) [ "ffd8ffdb", "ffd8ffe0", "47494638" ]
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
};
console.log(listOfFileSignatures); // Array []
```

[Heres the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3Gvp.png)

Comment: You aren't declaring `listOfFileSignatures` anywhere. BEFORE the `for` loop simply add `listOfFileSignatures = [];`

Comment: Declare it globally, just put `const listOfFileSignatures = []` before the `for (file...)` line.

Comment: @imvain2 I have `var listOfFileSignatures = [];` before the for loop.

Comment: @terrymorse I already have a `listOfFileSignatures` before the fore loop, I've edited the code example.

Comment: @simanacci, since you do have it declared, that means the problem is simply that your console is being ran BEFORE all of your `onloadend` calls are  being completed. Which means you will need to run your callback function that uses `listOfFileSignatures` in the onloadend of the LAST file in the list.

Comment: @imvain2 Is there a way to copy the array to the global  scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare listOfFileSignatures globally, but the signatures are computed asynchronously, so the list will be empty directly after the for loop. FileReader is always asynchronous, so you can't avoid that. One possibility to handle this is to check if the list is full inside onloadend (`listOfFileSignatures.length == uploadedFiles.length`) and then do what you want there.

A nicer approach is to use promises, like this:

```
var uploadedFiles = document.getElementById("notes").files;

Promise.all([...uploadedFiles].map(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var blob = file;

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onloadend = function readFirstFourBytes(e) {
        var arr = (new Uint8Array(e.target.result)).subarray(0, 4);
        var fileSignature = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            fileSignature += arr[i].toString(16);
        };
        resolve(fileSignature);
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);

}))).then(function(listOfFileSignatures) {
    // this will be called once, when all results are collected.
    console.log(listOfFileSignatures);
});
```

Additionally, reading all bytes and then select just the first 4 byte is inefficient. Improved version:

```
Promise.all([...uploadedFiles].map(file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var blob = file;

    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onloadend = function readFirstFourBytes(e) {
        var arr = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
        var fileSignature = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            fileSignature += arr[i].toString(16);
        };
        resolve(fileSignature);
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob.slice(0, 4));

}))).then(function(listOfFileSignatures) {
    // this will be called once, when all results are collected.
    console.log(listOfFileSignatures);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

fileReader.onload is asynchronous, console.log (listOfFileSignatures); is called before files have been read

one option is to create an external function that returns a promise, returning the listOfFileSignatures array

```
function getListFile() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        var blob = file;
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = function readFirstFourBytes(e) {
            var arr = (new Uint8Array(e.target.result)).subarray(0, 4);
            var fileSignature = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                fileSignature += arr[i].toString(16);
            };
            listOfFileSignatures.push(fileSignature);
            resolve(listOfFileSignatures);
        };
    }
}
```